# How can i filter JSON by key in JSX

Tags: json, reactjs, filtering, jsx

I have a problem when I try to filter a JSON data in React App...

My JSON:

```
function fakeListReports()
{
    return [

  {
    id: 0,
    project: {
      id: 7,
      name: "Music Arena",

      /...more datas.../

    },
    redacteur: "Ced",

    /...more datas.../

  },
  {
    id: 1,
    project: {
      id: 1,

      /...more datas.../

    },
    redacteur: "Ced",

    /...more datas.../

  },
  {
    id: 2,
    project: {
      id: 1,
      name: "Planet Express",

      /...more datas.../

    },
    redacteur: "Ced",

    /...more datas.../

  }
];
}
```

I would like to filter him by the id of the project. I would return a list with all the reports belonging at one project by his id...

I try with the filter function but she always returns an empty tab... I have tested many solutions but no success. And I'm convinced that filter function is the best way to reach a good result...

My JSX code:

```
const ListReportsByProject = ({ match }) => {
  const id = match.params;
  const [listReport, setListReport] = useState([]);
  const reports = fakeData.fakeListReports();

  const fetchReports = id => {
    console.log(reports);
    console.log(id.id);
    const reportsByProject = reports.filter(r => r.project.id === id.id);
    console.log(reportsByProject);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchReports(id);
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>test route</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Can you help me? I have no solution despite my many searches...

Thanks

Edit:

In the variable reportsByProject, When for example id.id = 1 I want to obtain a JSON with all and only the reports who the id of project = 1.

With this example, reportsByProject must be equal to:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    project: {
      id: 1,

      /...more datas.../

    },
    redacteur: "Ced",

    /...more datas.../

  },
  {
    id: 2,
    project: {
      id: 1,
      name: "Planet Express",

      /...more datas.../

    },
    redacteur: "Ced",

    /...more datas.../

  }
];
```

The filter function always return an empty tab.

Tu value of id.id is correct...

Comment: please show an example of the end result and strip down the data, most of this is irrelevant I think.

Comment: What do your console logs show?

Comment: `==id.id` is returning correct id?

Comment: Yes ==id.id is returning correct id.

Comment: I edited my question. 
I think it's more understandable now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

The problem came from the fact that id.id was of type string. With a parseInt the problem is solved!

Thanks to those who tried to help me.

```
 const fetchReports = id => {
    console.log(reports);
    console.log(id);
    const idProject = parseInt(id.id, 10);
    const reportsByProject = reports.filter((r) => r.project.id === idProject);
    console.log(reportsByProject);
};
```